# SSRS - Lookup only on certain columns in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services

I have a matrix table with a column group "Application questions" let's say these are in table 1. Some of  the questions have unique string values such as: Name, ID number, email address. But others have an integer value that relates to an actual value for a separate lookup table (table 2), for example, the values for the column "Gender" are 1, 2, 3, for Male, Female, Other. Is there a way in the lookup function that I can isolate the columns that only have integer values or alternatively ignore the other columns with unique string values?

Table1

```
NAME       ATTRIBUTE_id     ATTRIBUTE
-----------------------------------------
James      5                  1
James      6                  james@email.com
James      7                  8
```

Table2

```
Lookup_id       ATTRIBUTE_id     Description
-----------------------------------------
1                    5               Male
2                    5               Female
3                    5               Other
8                    7               New York
9                    7               Los Angeles
```

Output

```
NAME     |     Email      |    Gender     |     City
-------------------------------------------------------
James     james@email.com       Male          New York
```

Hope that makes sense!

Thank you.

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output based on that data otherwise it's difficult to visualise what you mean. Also look back over your old questions and either mark answers as accepted or add a response indicating why the answer is not accepted.

Comment: @AlanSchofield duly noted Alan! I've added some sample data above, hope that's helpful.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from joining the tables in your dataset query? It's almost always easier to do things like this in the dataset query. Also, show what your desired output should look like and include another attribute so we can see if they are in the same table or in separate tables.

Comment: I could do it in the query with pivots but the reason I want to do it in SSRS with a matrix is so that if a new category is added in the database, I don't have to go and alter the query as the matrix will automatically create another column when that category is added.

Comment: I meant doing all the joins in query not pivoting the results. I'll try to post an answer later today if I get time. I think if should be fairly simple to do now that I've seen more sample data.

Comment: Ok @AlanSchofield, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be easier to do in your dataset query.

Below I have recreated your sample data and added an extra person in to make sure it's working as expected.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Name varchar(10), AttributeID INT, AttributeMemberID varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t  VALUES 
('Mary', 5, '2'),
('Mary', 6, 'Mary@email.com'),
('James', 5, '1'),
('James', 6, 'james@email.com'),
('James', 7, '8')

DECLARE @AttributeMembers TABLE (AttributeMemberID INT, AttributeID int, Description varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @AttributeMembers  VALUES 
(1, 5, 'Male'),
(2, 5, 'Female'),
(3, 5, 'Other'),
(8, 7, 'New York'),
(9, 7, 'Los Angeles')
```

I also added in a new table which describes what each attribute is. We will use the output from this as column headers in the final SSRS matrix.

```
DECLARE @Attributes TABLE(AttributeID int, Caption varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Attributes VALUES 
(5, 'Gender'),
(6, 'Email'),
(7, 'City')
```

Finally we join all three togther and get a fairly normalised view for the data. The join is a bit messy as your current tables use the same column for both integer based lookups/joins and absolute string values. Hence the `CASE` in the `JOIN`

```
SELECT 
        t.Name,
        a.Caption,
        ISNULL(am.[Description], t.AttributeMemberID) as Label
    FROM @t t 
        JOIN @Attributes a on t.AttributeID = a.AttributeID
        LEFT JOIN @AttributeMembers am 
            on t.AttributeID = am.AttributeID 
            and 
                CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(t.AttributeMemberID) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE t.AttributeMemberID END as int)
                = am.AttributeMemberID
    ORDER BY Name, Caption, Label
```

This gives us the following output...

[image]

As you can see, this will be easy to put into a Matrix control in SSRS.

Row group by `Name, Column Group by` Caption`and data cell would be`Label`.

If you wanted to ensure the order of the columns, you could extend the `Attributes` table to include a `SortOrder` column, include this in the query output and use this in SSRS to order the columns by.

Hope that's clear enough.